# How to modify a php string variable in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using php4 and jquery, I have got a php string variable $content which stores a string as shown below.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>comments:</td>
        <td>Good</td>
         .....
         ...n rows
     </table>
  </html>
```

So, Now i want to change the color of **all occurrences of text "Good"** to red. So How to write a jquery function which takes a php string $content variable and changes the color of each "Good" word, (adds a style color:red) and returns it.

Comment: Have you read any of the Related questions yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure PHP solution:

```
echo str_replace('Good', '<span style="color:red">Good</span>', $content);
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access PHP variables in Javascript. Also, javascript works on the client side and PHP works on the server side.

I am unsure of the exact usage for this, but, here's my take on doing this:

```
// in javascript code
var x = "<?php echo $content; ?>"; // do take care of stripping quotes (")
x.replace("Good", "<span style='color:red'>Good</span>");
```

I guess that should do it.

Just to explain a bit more, on the server, PHP will dump the contents of the variable `$content` to the variable `x` in JS. On the client side, when JS is executed, it will pick this up and do the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("td").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Good/, '<span style="color:#f00">Good</span>')); 
});
```

This will look through each  cell and find if there is a text value of "Good" and wrap a span around it

Answer (score 0):

```
$content .= '<span class="red">';
$content .= {your existing code here}
$content .= '</span>';
```

After it you create a CSS Rule:

```
.red{ color:red; }
```

As you see you don't need jQuery at all.